# removing a border from div makes it hidden

Tags: php, css, html

So something weird is happening for me here... i have had borders on my divs for testing so i could see where they begin and end. Once i removed the border one of my divs contents disappears and i do not understand why...

here is my main html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EasyZag Admin</title>

        <!-- add the jQuery script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- add the jQWidgets framework -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
        <!-- add the css themes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href="stylesheets/basic.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.darkblue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='container'> 
            <div id="header">
                <div id='logo'>
                <img src="ezag_logo.jpeg" alt="eZag">
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        // Create a jqxMenu and set its width and height.
                        $("#jqxmenu").jqxMenu({ height: 30 , theme: 'darkblue'});
                        $("#main").height($('#container').height() - $('#header').height() - $('#footer').height() - 10);
                    });
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        $("#main").height($('#container').height() - $('#header ').height() - $('#footer').height() - 10);
                    });
                </script>

                <div id='jqxmenu'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li>Clients
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Add Client</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">All Clients</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><br />

            <div id="main">
                <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['section'])) {
                        //include which section
                    } else {
                        include "default.php";
                        echo "hello";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <center>Copyright 2012, EasyZag</center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS file

```
body, html { height: 99%; width: 99%;}
div {position: relative; border: 1px dotted;}   

#container {width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#E8F4FF; border-radius:25px; border: solid; border-color: } 
#header { float: left; height: 80px; width: 100%; }
#logo {float: left; width: 225px; height: 70px; padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;}
#jqxmenu {float: left; position: relative; top: 40px; left: 0px; }
#main {position: width: 100%; height: 50%; overflow: auto;}
#footer {float: left; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

And finally all the php include is follows:

```
Welcome to EasyZag Admin!<br />
<br />
Goals:<br />
<br />
```

Does anyone know why just changing 
    div {position: relative; border: 1px dotted;}
To 
    div {position: relative;}

in my css file would completely remove the div that has the php include in it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's really hidden, and not just shifting somewhere not visible? Removing a border removes the border's width from sizing calculations, causing document relows.

Comment: I usually find it best to use background color when cutting a design as having border will affect the sizing of the whole element which then may position differently when removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres an error in #main - you haven't included a value for the position property..

Comment: oh wow.. this was it.. i feel like an idiot haha thank you so much!

Comment: although it still seems weird that the border made a difference with the issue... anyways, doesn't matter any longer

Answer (score 0):

try adding the border with color with transparency.

```
border: 1px dashed transparent;
```

Since you used border with 1px, it means that you had 2 extra pixel vertically and horizontally. In other words, if you remove the border. If you were using `width = something` then your element might not get placed where the used to.

Using something like `width: auto;` and for height too would make element used that new 2 pixels.

Using transparent color might not be a good idea but it make sure that your border exists and you are still using that 2 extra pixel like before.. but they are transparent. If you are using background colors. It might be better to refactor your css.

On the other hand, I might suggest using backgrounds instead of border to check where are your elements.

If you set different colors, its going to be easy to check your layout and background color doesn't affect size of elements.

Comment: thank you very much, the transparent works for now, and i will go back and reevaluate it at some point to try to actually solve the problem..